# How to open Outlook messages stored in the file system from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to open msg (Outlook item) files saved in my desktop folder (C:\Desktop\Index) and search for attachments (single/zip file).

I am getting

> 'object doesn't support this property or method' error for:

`Set openMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileItem.Path)`

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetMSG()
*True includes sub folders
*False to check only listed folder
   ListFilesInFolder "C:\Desktop\Index\", True
End Sub

Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
    Dim strFile, strFileType, strAttach As String
    Dim openMsg As MailItem

    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFolderpath As String

    'where to save attachments
    strFolderpath = "C:\Desktop\Index\Attachments\"

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files

        strFile = FileItem.Name

        ' This code looks at the last 4 characters in a filename
        ' If we wanted more than .msg, we'd use Case Select statement
        strFileType = LCase$(Right$(strFile, 4))
        If strFileType = ".msg" Then
            Debug.Print FileItem.Path

            Set openMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileItem.Path)
            openMsg.Display
            'do whatever

            Set objAttachments = openMsg.Attachments
            lngCount = objAttachments.Count

            If lngCount > 0 Then

                For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

                    ' Get the file name.
                   strAttach = objAttachments.Item(i).Filename

                    ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
                    strAttach = strFolderpath & strAttach

                    ' Save the attachment as a file.
                    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strAttach

                Next i
            End If
            openMsg.Close olDiscard

            Set objAttachments = Nothing
            Set openMsg = Nothing

            ' end do whatever
        End If
    Next FileItem
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this before the error:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileItem.Path)
```

When you are using `Application`, it refers to the Excel application and not to the Outlook application. And the Excel `Application` does not support `CreateItemFromTemplate`.

You can also use early binding:

```
Dim OutApp As New Outlook.Application
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileItem.Path)
```

Comment: Thanks Vityata - I am able to save attachments to folder now, could you please let me know how i can save file with the subject name?